# Redirect page depending on form submission in Jquery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, redirect

I'm working on a page that should redirect depending on what the user enters in the form, and I can't seem to figure it out. New to Javascript, and eager to learn!

Here is the html:

```
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="navcontainer">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#item1">Home</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#item2">Scents</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#item3">About</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#item4">Contact</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
<div id="content">
        <p>Hi, how are you feeling today?</p>
        <form> <input id="feels" type="text" name="feeling" size="35" onchange="checkfeels(#feels.value);"> 
        <input type="submit" value="submit" >
        </form>
</div>
```

And the Javascript I have so far:

```
function checkfeels(myFeels) {
        switch (myFeels) 
        {
        case "good":
            document.location.href = 'scents.html';
            break
        case "bad":
            alert(2);
            document.location.href = 'scents2.html';
        default: 
            alert("whatever");
        }
    }
```

Any help is really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is supposed to happen?  What actually happens?  What browser(s) did you try?  Have you enabled debugging in your browser?  If yes, did it report any errors?

Comment: I just want the user to answer the question, "How are you feeling?", and when they enter their answer, they should be directed to a new page depending on their answer. I've tried in Firefox and Chrome, and I didn't think to enable debugging..I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following code:

```
checkfeels($('#feels').val());
return false;
```

in the form onsubmit attribute.

Comment: When I do that, I'll just be taken to 

    index.html?feeling=good 

rather than a new page. Am I doing something wrong..or do I just not understand how forms work?

Answer (score 2):

Put the

```
return checkfeels(this.elements.feeling.value)
```

in the form onsubmit attribute.

"feeling" in current case is the name of input field. <input type="text" name="feeling" > in your code.

And add

```
return false;
```

to the end of the checkfeels function to prevent default action (submiting form to server).

Also, you can pass to function whole form, for example:

```
return checkfeels(this)
```

And work already with whole form in checkfeels function.

```
function checkfeels(form) {
   var feeling = form.elements.feeling.value;
   var otherField = form.elements.otherField.value;

   // code with your logic here

   return false; // prevent default action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get what the user types with #feels.value (it seems that you make a mistake between jQuery syntax and javascript).

You can do that in pure javascript :

```
function checkfeels() {
    var myFeels = document.getElementById('feels').value;
    switch (myFeels) {
        case "good":
            document.location.href = 'scents.html';
            break
        case "bad":
            alert(2);
            document.location.href = 'scents2.html';
        default: 
            alert("whatever");
    }
}
```

You get what the user type with :

```
document.getElementById('feels').value
```

and you don't need to give any parameters to the function.

If you use jQuery, you can get the value with :

```
$('#feels').val();
```